# React Native - Android Handle click on notification to navigate to specific screen

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-navigation, android-push-notification

I used this library https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification for remote push notification, onNotification method fired only when receive notification, no when tapped notification , i need to handle notification click to open specific screen in my app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer rn-firebase plugin. There are methods available for handling notification tap. Inside that method call you can use the react navigation to navigate to particular screen.

https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
onAction: function (notification) {
   console.log("ACTION:", notification.action);
   console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
   // process the action
},
```

add this to the inside configue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).